# How to auto select the first item in datalist (html 5)?

Tags: html

How can i select automatically the first suggestion in the list?

```
  <input list="browsers">

 <datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

this codes came from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: I don't think it's possible without javascript

Answer (score 5):

Just give this way:

```
<input list="browsers" value="Internet Explorer" />
```

#### Fiddle:

```html
<input list="browsers" value="Internet Explorer" />

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer" />
  <option value="Firefox" />
  <option value="Chrome" />
  <option value="Opera" />
  <option value="Safari" />
</datalist>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is an AutoSuggest plugin, which is something similar to what you see in Google Search, right? That functionality is not there in `dataList`.

Comment: Not exactly, this kind of static list will do. What i need is to auto select the first item in the list so that when the user hit enter, the value that is currently selected will be submitted.

Comment: @jaytemp I still don't get you what you want. Can you be more clear?

Comment: sorry for my vague question. what i want is to autofocus on the first item on list while typing. So that i will not use arrow keys to select the item.

Comment: I want this done while typing!

Comment: @Salem Like [Select2](https://select2.org/)?

Comment: I only saw it on _Windows accounting_  application, in the input box if I start typing `ap` it's will automatically complete it to `apple` inside the box , even if the options available continue only the whole word `sweet apple`  it will select it to me if I just start trying `app` . I can create my own script, but it will take from me days to finish. BTW google had better datalist usability, if if highlight it with arrow key it will be filled into the input, while by default you need to hit enter to get it selected .